# JS window width html5 video element responsive

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Alright I have been trying a lot of different things but can't get it to work. So I am asking here.

I have 3 video elements on a page. One for desktop, tablet and smartphone. Now I need to remove video elements depending on the screen size.

```
So when screen size is < 767:
Smartphone = visible
Tablet = removed
Desktop = removed

Screen size is >=767 && <980
Smartphone = removed
Tablet = visible
Desktop = removed

Screen size is >=980
Smartphone = removed
Tablet = removed
Desktop = visible
```

CSS media queries aint working because the video elements keep playing. Yes on mobile it is prevented for autoplaying but on desktop browser resize it plays this should not happen. So display:none; is out of the question.

So I need to create some JS magic I guess. This is what I have so far I am trying to fill in the blank pages with everything I can come up with but so far it did not result in the desired effect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(this).width() < 767)
        WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE
    else if ($(this).width() >= 767 && $(this).width() < 980)            
        WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE            
    else if ($(this).width() >= 980)                        
        WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE            
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36unpxj0/2/

In the above fiddle you can see the code entirely and fiddle around with it. Thank you very much for helping.

PS: jQuery solutions are just as welcome as pure JS but please tell if it is JS or jQuery.

EDIT 1:

As usual I am going to keep searching and adding info to this post!
I found the following which could do the trick:

```
$("#video-ID").first().attr('src','')
```

Or

```
$("#video-ID").empty().remove();
```

I tried both but with no luck: See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/36unpxj0/3/

EDIT 2:

Alright got the answer from CitizenDelta and it is working in the JSFiddle therefore I have accepted his answer. However this is currently not working inside a Joomla website. So I am going to keep looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a demo, I hope, it is what you need : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/36unpxj0/4/)

Steps :

1. I hide every video (pauseAndHideAll function)
2. I detect the screen (showTheGoodOne function)
3. I show and play the video correpsonding

In JavaScript, I have just made this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function pauseAndHide($element) {
    $element.get(0).pause();
    $element.hide();
}

function showTheGoodOne() {
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $('#smartphonevid').show();
        $('#smartphonevid').get(0).play();
    } else if ($(window).width() >= 767 && $(this).width() < 980)   {
        $('#tabletvid').show();
        $('#tabletvid').get(0).play();
    } else if ($(window).width() >= 980)  {
        $('#desktopvid').show();
        $('#desktopvid').get(0).play();
    } 
}

function pauseAndHideAll() {   
    $('video').each(function() {
        pauseAndHide($(this));         
    });     
}

pauseAndHideAll();
showTheGoodOne();

$(window).resize(function () {
    pauseAndHideAll();
    showTheGoodOne();
});
});
```

**Optionnal improvment :**

Maybe you could detect the current time of the video playing, then you resume the other video to this time.

Comment: Thank you my previous comment was incorrect did not read your answer correctly. Sorry for that.

Comment: Yes, I have put the way it works in my updated post above

Comment: This is pure JS so no need for jQuery! Right?

Comment: Alright it is working perfectly on jsfiddle but when I insert the code inside a Joomla module it ain't. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe you don't give enough information ^^. Try to search, and maybe open a new question, because the problem is here different ^^ (And resolve this question if it works)

Answer (score 0):

### Hope this helps you is just css

```css
#video-bg {
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   padding-top: 30px;
   position: relative;
}
#video-bg > video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="video-bg" class="smartphone">
    <video autoplay muted loop controls id="smartphonevid">
        <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
            <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
                <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but what are you actually suggesting here! I can see a difference with the padding but this has nothing to do with stopping video elements from playing? Maybe I am getting it wrong!

Comment: This is an elastic video fit on your port view and just use one video element. No need media queries. Try running the snippet on full screen and resize the window.

Comment: Alright nice. How to make this work with 3 different videos for smartphone, tablet and desktop. Please have a look at the fiddle.net/36unpxj0/4/ and change it please how you think it should be. Really interested in it.

Comment: why you need 3 videos that show the same video element, source and configuration (according to your fiddle)?

If you need different sources and configuration for tablets, smartphones or pcs, maybe you need to verify the client on the server and build your html according the client. And with this elastic video it gonna fi on portview.

Comment: It is showing the same video element just as an example. It is a Joomla Module so the user selects which element to use for which video. Your second suggestion is correct and will look into that. Thank you for the elastic CSS as you see in the fiddle that part was already covered. Once again thank you very much for taking the time to reply and giving your answer.